# Actions - What are objects and context

Tags: 7, actions

Can somebody explain to me what the difference is between an object and context within the advanced action setup please.

I understand what an object is but am failing to understand what context is.

Thanks.

Comment: What is "the advanced action setup"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are talking about the $context variable (and I think you do), then the official description is: an associative array containing extra information about what triggered the action call, with $context['hook'] giving the name of the hook that resulted in this call to actions_do() (from here:  http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!actions.inc/function/actions_do/7)

But if you want to understand it better, this page is very useful: http://www.sysarchitects.com/node/47

Answer (score 0):

The context is used to identify how the action is being triggered so that, if necessary, it can handle the object differently — e.g. an action that has to do different things depending on whether a node is being inserted for the first time or updated.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal supports a trigger/action system. So you can easily give drupal some object id(s) and say I want these Actions to occur to this object, at some time or context.

Here is a small example from some code I run via drush in a php-eval:

```
$q = new EntityFieldQuery();
$types_to_publish = array('page');
$q->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', $types_to_publish, 'IN');
$results = $q->execute();
foreach ($results['node'] as $node) {
  $current_node = node_load($node->nid);
  $migrator_user = user_load_by_name('d7migrator_user');
  $current_node->uid = $migrator_user->uid;
  $actions = array('node_publish_action', 'node_save_action');
  $context['node'] = $current_node;
  actions_do($actions, $current_node, $context, NULL, NULL);
}
drupal_set_message('Done publishing content.');
```

I do this because I'm migrating some node via node_export and then apply the Workbench module and currently need to re-save nodes to that Workbench can properly set the publish state for the given NIDs. We dont need to supply a `$context` here beyond the `node` because I'm not hooking into the lifecycle of a page request or form POST processing.